# Page not showing in Android Browser

Tags: android, html, css

I wound really appreciate any and all help with thisclient because i have viewed the source-code and can not figure out why just the  and nothing inside it is being displayed in this web page i am developing.

Here is the url: the-irf.com/mob

Also if it helps, ive notoced this occurs in the Android browser.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You need to describe what is not working. Looking on my Android browser I see a page just fine.

Comment: @Tom sorry for not doing so. Nothing is showing up on my Droid X running Android 2.3 except the body's background-image

Comment: I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.x. The site shows me a logo, and 3 headers/text boxes (or whatever they are). So your problem seems to be version specific.

Comment: @Tom okay, thats what one is supposed to see right now. Hmm okay thats odd. But it helps, thank you

Comment: Post your code and I'm sure someone will take a look at it.

Comment: @Tom the code is just the source, which can be viewed in most browsers by right-clicking.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I reproduced it using a Moto Droid user agent. The problem is your style code:

```
<style type="text/css">footer nav{ background:transparent url(assets/images/nav.png) no-repeat center center; } @media only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){ footer nav{ background:transparent url(assets/images/retina/1.5/nav@1.5x.png) no-repeat center center; background-size:100%; } } @media only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){ footer nav{ background:transparent url(assets/images/retina/2/nav@2x.png) no-repeat center center; } }</style><style type="text/css">.contentBox{ background:#ff0000; }
```

It is a bit of a mess and I'm not sure what you are doing, but remove this code and it then works. I guess something in there doesn't want to play nice on earlier versions of Android.

Also note I see a syntax issue with your html code, you have a missing `>` with `nav`.

Comment: I ended up approaching that style in a different manner / rewriting the code and that fixed it, but I did not notice the missing angle-bracket, thank you :-)

Comment: in what desktop browser and how did you get it to act like a droid? Im asking because that seems like a useful technique for debugging.